# Are private transactions possible in Ethereum?

Tags: transactions, ethereum, private

I'm trying to learn about ethereum technology and posibilites and I'd like get some info about this. I'm just a totally begginer at this so please, excuse me if I'm asking something stupid.

Let's say I want to use ethereum to exchange assests between several vendors.  According to what I have read all the transactions are shared in the blockchain, so the amount transfered could be seen for everyone and everyone could see that transfer has happened.

Let say I have to providers A and B. I'd like to be able to have transactions with A without B knowing the amount of the transaction or even the existence of the transaction.

Is that even possible?

I have red that could be done with hyperledger fabric and something called Channels. Is that true? IS there any way to do the same with Ethereum?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ethereum supports private transaction in Solidity smart contracts and crypto primitives in those smart contracts. You just need to program your smart contract to take advantage of those. Some privacy-focused solutions are purely on-chain (TornadoCash) while other solutions need somebody to run layer two specific node software.

Here are some examples

- [TornadoCash](https://tornado.cash/) - private transactions for ETH and any
  ERC-20 token
- [Aztec](https://developers.aztec.network/) - layer 2 scaling and private transaction solution on the top of Ethereum
- [zkSync](https://zksync.io/) - layer 2 scaling and private transaction solution on the top of Ethereum

Comment: - zkSync offers no privacy currently. It is on the roadmap but who knows if and when it will happen. but it is an excellent L2 scaling protocol, I use it everyday :)
- Aztec 2.0 is live but very Beta, I didn't test it.
- Tornado cash is reliable but a very old model of putting your money in a large pool than sneakly fishing it out later on. The more you wait the more private it gets, also if you put x in and there and then there is some RL evidence a person you know received ~x, well, it is not THAT private is it? So, be real smart with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no analogue of the channel mechanism in the Etherleum like in the Hyperleger Fabric. In fact, each channel in HL Fabric is a separate permissioned blockchain.

To close the content of transactions in Ethereum, there are special "add-ons", such as a Tessera in Quorum, which provide work with private contracts.

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect, as you can implement private transactions in Solidity and on any EVM compatible chain.